# Perform multiple operations and commit

Tags: java, api-design

A system handles two types of resources. There are write and delete APIs for managing the resources. A client (user) will use a library API to manage these resources. Each resource write (or create) will result in updating a store or a database.

The API would look like:

1) Create Library client. The user will use the returned client to operate on the resources.

```
MyClient createClient(); //to create the client
```

2) MyClient interface. Providing operations on a resource

```
writeResourceType1(id);
deleteResourceType1(id);

writeResourceType2(id);
deleteResourceType2(id);
```

Some resources are dependent on the other. The user may write them out-of-order (might write a resource before writing its dependent). In order to prevent the system from having an inconsistent state, all changes (resource updates) will be written to a staging location. The changes will be written to the actual store *only* when the user indicates he/she has written everything.

This means I would need a *commit* kind of method in the above `MyClient` interface. So, access pattern will look like

```
Client client = provider.createClient();
..
client.writeResourceType1(..)

client.writeResourceType1(..)

client.deleteResourceType2(..)

client.commit(); //<----
```

I'm not comfortable having the commit API in the `MyClient` interface. I feel it is polluting it and a wrong it is a wrong level of abstraction.

Is there a better way to handle this?

---

Another option I thought of is getting **all** the updates as part of a single call. This API would act as a Batch API

```
writeOrDelete(List<Operations> writeAndDeleteOpsForAllResources)
```

The downside of this is this the user has to combine all the operations on their end to call this. This is also stuffing too much into a single call. So, I'm not inclined to this approach.

Comment: If your API concept is transactional, how do you want to identify when to commit a transaction?

Comment: @Smutje the intent will come from the user. Once they have written the full set of resources, they will say, *I'm done*

Comment: So, a commit, basically.

Comment: IMO you are asking the wrong question: Software or API development is not just about whether the developer likes the API. The main question is if that API models reality in a suitable way. And different from many standard CRUD scenarios here you describe a case in which an API user (or maybe even an end user) determines the end of a transaction. In order to enable her to do that, a commit method (whatever you might name it) seems to be a good thing to have. So why modeling a contrived solution if a simple and obvious solution which models reality already exists?

Answer (score 10):

While both ways that you've presented can be viable options, the thing is that at some point in time, the user must somehow say: "Ok, these are are my changes, take them all or leave them". This is exactly what commit is IMO.
And this alone makes necessary some kind of call that must present in the API.

In the first approach that you've presented its obviously explicit, and is done with `commit` method.
In the second approach its rather implicit and is determined by the content of the list that you pass into `writeOrDelete` method.

So in my understanding, commit must exist somehow, but the question is how do you make it less "annoying" :)

Here are couple of tricks:

**Trick 1: Builder / DSL**

```
interface MyBuilder {
   MyBuilder addResourceType1(id);
   MyBuilder addResourceType2(id);
   MyBuilder deleteResourceType1/2...();
   BatchRequest build();
}

interface MyClient {
   BatchExecutionResult executeBatchRequest(BatchRequest req);
}
```

This method is more or less like the second method, however it has a clear way of "adding resources". A single point of creation (pretty much like `MyClient` not, just I believe that eventually it will have more methods, so maybe its a good idea to separate. As you stated: "I'm not comfortable having the commit API in the MyClient interface. I feel it is polluting it and a wrong it is a wrong level of abstraction")
Additional argument for this approach is that now you know that there is a builder and its an "abstraction to go" in your code that uses this, you don't have to think about passing a reference to the list, think about what happens if someone calls stuff like `clear()` on this list, and so on and so forth. The builder has a precisely defined API of what can be done.

In terms of creating the builder:

You can go with something like Static Utility class or even add a method to `MyClient`:

```
// option1

public class MyClientDSL {
   private MyClientDSL {}
   public static MyBuilder createBuilder();
}

// option 2
public interface MyClient {
    MyBuilder newBuilder();
}
```

References to this approach: JOOQ (they have DSL like this), OkHttp that have builders for Http Requests, Bodies and so forth (decoupled from the OkHttpClient itself).

**Trick 2: Providing an execution code block**

Now this can be tricky to implement depending on what kind of environment do you run in, 
but basically an idea is borrowed from Spring: 
In order to guarantee a transaction while working with databases they provide a special annotation `@Transactional` that while placed on the methods basically says: "everything inside the method is running in transaction, I'll commit it by myself so that the user won't deal with transactions/commits at all. I'll also roll back upon exception"

So in code it looks like:

```
class MyBusinessService {
       private MyClient myClient; // injected
         @Transactional
         public void doSomething() {
             myClient.addResourceType1();
             ...
             myClient.addResourceType2();
             ...  
         }
}
```

Under the hood they should maintain ThreadLocals to make this possible in multithreaded environment, but the point is that the API is clean. The method `commit` might exist but probably won't be used at the most of the cases, leaving alone the really sophisticated scenarios where the user might really "need" this fine-grained control.

If you use spring/ any other containter that manages your code, you can integrate it with spring (the technical way of doing this is out of scope of this question, but you get the idea).

If not, you can provide the most simplistic way of it:

```
public class MyClientCommitableBlock {

    public static <T> T executeInTransaction(CodeBlock<T> someBlock)
            builder) {

          MyBuilder builder = create...;
          T result = codeBlock(builder);
          // build the request, execute and commit
          return result;
      }
}
```

Here is how it looks:

```
static import MyClientCommitableBlock.*;
public static void main() {

     Integer result = executeInTransaction(builder -> {
        builder.addResourceType1();
        ... 
        return 42;
     });
}

// or using method reference:

    class Bar {
       Integer foo() {
         return executeInTransaction(this::bar);    
       } 

       private Integer bar(MyBuilder builder) {
         ....
       }
    }
```

In this approach a builder while still defining precisely a set of APIs might not have an "explicit" commit method exposed to the end user. Instead it can have some "package private" method to be used from within the `MyClientCommitableBlock` class

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the first approach. But a con in that is that all the resources will be written only in the `executeBatchRequest`. If there are a lot of resources, that call can take a long time (the resource data/file has to be sent over the network). I guess it is *equivalent* to batching all the requests in one call but using a builder reduces the burden on the client.

Comment: Yes of course, I haven't addressed the nature of the data, and it can indeed influence the design. On the other hand if you want to send data eagerly who knows maybe the client will discard the transaction at the end of the day, so the the heavy resources will be sent over the network in vain... There is always a trade-off..

Comment: BTW, Another concern, what happens if there is so much data that it can overwhelm the server (given there are a lot of clients that can send the data simultaneously)...

Comment: If you manage to create an API that will abstract the background sending operation off the client - it will be much better for him/her of course as long as it meets the requirements. For example you can internally maintain some queue of objects to be sent to server and start sending as long as you have something in hand. The server could store this temp data in some durable temp storage with TTL / use 'status' column like our colleage Clement has suggested, the point is that its an implementation concern / optimization feature is you wish. Al least IMO :)

Comment: A very elegant approach, and also nice naming, and using the builder pattern to define "transaction" blocks!

Answer (score 0):

Try if this suits you

Let us have a flag in staging table with column named `status`

**Status Column values**

```
New : Record inserted by user
ReadyForProcessing : Records ready for processing
Completed : Records processed and updated in Actual Store
```

Add this below method instead of `commit()`, and once user invokes this method/service, pick up the records which are for this user and which are in `status: New` and post it into the Actual Store from the staging location

```
client.userUpdateCompleted();
```

There is another option as well let us take out the client intervention by giving `client.commit(); or client.userUpdateCompleted();` and instead we can have a `batch process using Scheduler` which runs at specific intervals which scans the Staging Table and populates the meaningful and user update completed records into the Actual Store

Comment: I guess this focuses on how to implement the staging logic. Handling the staging and separating the *partial* resource update with the actual *prod* resources is not a problem. I'm looking for how to design the `commit` (`userUpdateCompleted`) method as part of API

Comment: If you look at the client interface, it has CRUD methods on the resources. Having a *commit* method seems odd to me